# How to avoid hard referencing in Generic Service Locator?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

Kindly look into the below code

```
using EmployeeRepositories.SingularRepositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LocateService
{
    public class ServiceLocator : IService
    {
        public Dictionary<object, object> servicecontainer = null;
        public ServiceLocator()
        {
            servicecontainer = new Dictionary<object, object>();
            servicecontainer.Add(typeof(IEmployeeRepository), new EmployeeRepository());
            servicecontainer.Add(typeof(IDepartmentRepository), new DepartmentRepository());
        }
        public T GetService<T>()
        {
           return (T)servicecontainer[typeof(T)];

        }
    } 
}
```

There is a hard referencing.

Is there any way by which I can avoid it?

Comment: Why not use DI instead of a service locator pattern?

Comment: I am aware of that...though not trying to reinvent the wheel,but the sake of own learning trying to do something own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is a hard referencing.
>
> Is there any way by which I can avoid it?

No.

When you build an application that uses IoC, the idea is to make the application loosely-coupled. This is one reason why the [service locator is considered anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/): your application will be tightly coupled to the service locator and there is effectively no way to separate your application from it. On the other hand, if you use constructor injection it is possible to make your application completely unaware of the container that provides its dependencies or the concrete types it provides.

Unlike the rest of the application, the container is the only place where we *do* want coupling. We need this coupling in order to tell the container what dependencies to put where. Therefore, the hard referencing is intentional within the container.

That said, what you are doing is not duplicating what DI containers do. The primary purpose of DI containers is to compose *object graphs* of dependencies into applications. What you are doing is storing individual instances with effectively no way to inject dependencies into them, no way to control their lifetime, no way to dispose them, etc. What will you do if your `EmployeeRepository` requires a dependency (such as the Entity Framework context)? How will you ensure the context is properly disposed? You should really pick an available DI container instead of trying to reinvent the wheel because there are many things such as this that have already been thought through and thoroughly tested, such as giving each instance a separate lifetime that is controlled by the container.